# How to make file path to get data from another excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel

Heres i have which is not working
In cell

```
 A1 C:\HR\Time\July2017\[1-July.xls]
 A2 Sheet1
 A3 B15
```

How i concatenate these to get data from another excel file 1-July.xls data, which is in b15

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for an external reference is in the order of

Drive letter\path[workbook name.xlsx]SheetName!CellReference

You have a cell reference before you even hit the sheet name.

If you want to ensure a correct reference, open both workbooks. Then pick any cell in the receiving workbook, enter a = sign, click to the source workbook, select the correct sheet and select the correct cell. Then hit the Enter key.

While both workbooks are open, the cell with the link to the other file will show as

```
='[Source File.xlsx]The sheet with the data'!$A$1
```

When the source workbook is closed, the cell with the reference will look like this:

```
='C:\Users\doofus\Documents[Source File.xlsx]The sheet with the data'!$A$1
```

Note how the path and/or the file name are enclosed in single quotes.

An external reference can, of course, also refer to a range of cells, as a source for a Sum() or a Vlookup, for example.

```
=SUM('C:\Users\doofus\Documents[Source File.xlsx]The sheet with the data'!$A$1:$A$200)
```

Or

```
=Vlookup(A1,'C:\Users\doofus\Documents[Source File.xlsx]The sheet with the data'!$A$1:$D$200,3,False)
```